# String.matchAll is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am creating a package in node to parse and manipulate csv and needed to use `String.matchAll()` and I got an error saying `str.matchAll is not a function`. I tried switching to `str.match()` and got the same error. I tried to console.log each and both returned undefined. I typed `node -v` into the visual studio code powershell and it spat out v10.16.3

my code

```
fs = require('fs');

class Table {
    //the function I needed it for
    removeRow(header, value){
        let regLine = "";
        for(let i=0; i<this.colArr.length; i++){
            if (this.colArr[i][0]==header){
                regLine+=value+",";
            }else{
                regLine+=".*,"
            }
        }
        regLine = "\n"+regLine.substring(0,regLine.length-2)+"\n";
        let regex = new RegExp(regLine);

        let removed = this.text.matchAll(regex);//this line
        let newText = this.text.replace(regex,"\n");
        fs.writeFile(this.link, newText);
        this.update();
        return removed;
    }
}
```

At the line marked it throws the error `this.text is not a function` I console.logged `typeof(this.text)` and it gave string so I don't know whats going on

Comment: Can you please show us your code?

Comment: Are you sure that str is a String? How are you setting its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.matchAll is only available from Node.js 12.0 onwards (see compatibility here: [string.matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll)).

String.match however should be available from early versions of Node.js.

Here's an example I've created of it in action (Node v10.16.0): https://repl.it/repls/PunctualRareHypotenuse

I'd suggest also ensuring that the object in question is a string just to be sure!

Also if it's easy for you to upgrade, try installing [Node.js 12](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Code:

```js
var str = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var regexp = /[A-E]/g;
var matches_array = str.match(regexp);

console.log(matches_array);
```

Comment: Occam's razor: `this.text` is not a string.

Comment: @JaredSmith it most certainly is a string

Comment: So it's likely you just need to upgrade your Node.js install, or maybe use a workaround. Node 12 is on LTS now, so it should be good to install.

Comment: @Matt-the-Marxist if it doesn't have a `match` property, it isn't a string. `String.prototype.match` has been around since 1999. Are you testing it in Netscape Navigator?

Comment: @JaredSmith While trying to troubleshoot I put `console.log(typeof(this.text))` just before the `this.text.match(regex)` and it logged string. I am running things in vs code

Comment: @Matt-the-Marxist I can think of at least two possibilities off the top of my head then. 1. `console.log` is *not* guaranteed to run synchronously: if `this.text` is being set by an async operation it's possible it's logging after the set but attempting to match the regex before. Try setting it to a dummy constant string in the constructor. 2. It's a bug in your particular version of VS Code. As I said, `String.prototype.match` has been in node since the beginning. And VS Code is an electron app, based on chrome, which has also had it since the 1st version.

Comment: @JaredSmith to set `this.text` I am using `fs.readFileSync(this.link).toString();`

Comment: @Matt-the-Marxist IDK then. Try just setting it to 'foobar' in the constructor and see if you still get the error. If the `console.log` says it's type string, also try `console.log(this.text.match)` and you should get something like `f { [native code] }`.